# Send a Socket from JSP file to Java application?

Tags: java, sockets, jsp

I'm new with JSP(please newbie...), I'm doing a use case diagram so I'm stuck in the design was due to a small question .... I explain in short words:
Is it possible to send a socket(TCP or UDP) from a JSP web application, to a Java  server (JAR)?
I already found  [this example](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=97) , but is it in the opposite direction (Java Server to JSP  WEB) ... I want a confirmation, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You're using the wrong words, though: the _socket_ is not what is sent. I'm not sure what this has to do with JSP files, unless you're talking about scriptlets (in which case: don't). Have you tried writing any actual code?

Comment: I send a simple text with the socket from Web(JSP) to Java Server,I am currently in the design phase, so I collect information for my project.... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into 'KnockKnock Server-Client' example from Java. This shows implementation of both client and server socket. Good luck.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html